# CodeIgniter Escaping String

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying to insert a join into a query, like so:

```
$this->db->join(
"(SELECT DISTINCT(fo.Order_ID)
FROM order fo
INNER JOIN order_item foi ON fo.Order_ID = foi.Order_ID
INNER JOIN product_group fpg ON fpg.Product_ID = foi.Product_ID
INNER JOIN group fg ON fg.Group_ID = fpg.Group_ID
WHERE Group_Name IN". $groups.")G",
'G.Order_ID = o.Order_ID',
'inner');
```

`$groups` is an array, and since I can't use `$this->db->where_in()`, I escape it with:

```
$groups = array_map(function($group){return $this->db->escape($group);}, $groups);
$groups = '(' . implode(',', $groups).')';
```

This works fine for most inputs, but doesn't seem to actually escape the string.
For example, if 
`$groups = array('^*&', '?!?')`, the database throws the error:

```
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'NULL!'
```

And the relevant (breaking) part of the query is:

```
WHERE Group_Name IN('^*&','NULL!
```

How do I process the array properly?

Answer (score 0):

if

> WHERE Group_Name IN". $groups.")G",

and

> $groups is an array
>
> $groups = array('^*&', '?!?');

then

```
$this->db->join("
...
...
WHERE Group_Name IN ('".join( "','" , $groups )."')G",
....
```

which should produce a partial string of:

```
WHERE Group_Name IN ('^*&','?!?')G",
```